# Why does the C program(.exe) stop working?

Tags: c, pointers

I try to access and store the data from a .ini file into an array in my `main` program. To verify that the data is really stored I also print them out( and they seem to be the right ones). However , every time I run the main program it executes and then theres a pop up window that says that the .exe file has stopped working. Could somebody take a look and tell me what's wrong.

.ini file is :

```
 [key]
 title= A,H,D
```

C program:

```
var[100];
LPCSTR ini="C:\conf.ini";
GetPrivateProfileString("key", "title", 0, var, 100,ini);
int i=0;
char* arr[10];
char* buffer;
for(buffer=strtok(var, ",");buffer;buffer=strtok(NULL, ","))
{
    if (buffer !=NULL)
    {
       puts("")
       strcpy(arr[i], buffer);
       printf("the value is %S \n", arr[i]);
       i++;
    }
}
printf("first value %s", arr[0]);
printf("second value %s", arr[1]);
printf("third value %s", arr[2]);
```

Output I get looks like this:

```
  The value is A 

  The value is H 

  The value is D 
  first value A 
  second value H 
  third value D
```

Comment: for something this small there is no reason not to post the entire code..

Comment: `"C:\conf.ini"` --> `"C:\\conf.ini"`. also `if (buffer !=NULL)` This is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a typo in the closing `]`, and keeping that apart,

```
  strcpy(arr[i], buffer];
```

`arr[i]` is uninitialized here. Trying to write into uninitialised memory  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:** Before making use of `arr[i]`, you need to allocate memory to that. You can have a look at [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of functions for dynamic memory allocation.

FWIW, you may want to have a look at [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) also.

Comment: or simply declare it as 2 dimensional array with static size, you declare var of size 100 only so that could be the correct minimum size for the inner arr.